# Best pay per click book advertising

Tags: advertising

I think my web site is good for advertising books. It contains programming tutorials in Turkish. However there no good ads program in Turkey and Turkish users can't buy books on amazon etc. So is there a nice book ads program that pays per click?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use AdSense but filter it so it only shows links to sites about books?